# Excel Formula Help - Find mode of a row of text values, but exclude "?"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've made a 'Summary' worksheet which I need to tell me the most frequent text value from a row on another tab ('Company Ltd'), but to exclude the value '?'.

This is what I have, which does work fine to give me the mode, but as the row contains dropdown lists in each cell (made in 'data validation') which have a default '?' value, I need to exclude these to stop the mode being '?' and I can't work out how to add this to the below formula.  I'm definitely not an Excel whizz!

=INDEX('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,MODE(MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0)))

Hope you can help!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following formula determines the most frequent value. If that happens to be "?" then it returns the second most frequent value.

**These are array formulas, you have to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when you enter them**

`=IF(INDEX('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,MODE(MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0)))<>"?",INDEX('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,MODE(MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0))),INDEX('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,MAX(IF(MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0)<MODE(MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0)),MATCH('Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51,0)))))`

Alternatively, you could name the range 'Company Ltd'!$E$51:$CZ$51 as "rng" and use the following, less cluttered formula:

`=IF(INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(rng,rng,0)))<>"?",INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(rng,rng,0))),INDEX(rng,MAX(IF(MATCH(rng,rng,0)<MODE(MATCH(rng,rng,0)),MATCH(rng,rng,0)))))`

And Lastly, if you need to be able to handle blank cells (this converts them to ? and they are excluded):

`=IF(INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),0)))<>"?",INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),0))),INDEX(rng,MAX(IF(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),0)<MODE(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),0)),MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),SUBSTITUTE(rng,"","?"),0)))))`

Comment: Thanks for your help Valon - sorry for the late reply, the notification was in my Junk Mail folder. This worked great!

Comment: You're welcome, if this was the best answer please accept it as the solution for this thread.